# $(A-B)\cap C=(A\cap C) -(B\cap C)?$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Is it right
>   $$(A-B)\cap C=(A\cap C) -(B\cap C)?$$

Actually, I want to show 
$$m((A-B)\cap C)=m((A\cap C) -(B\cap C))=m((A\cap C) -(B\cap C))=m(A\cap C)-m(B\cap C)$$
where $m$ is a measure.

Comment: The title question is correct.  But in general, this part is not correct: $m((A\cap C) -(B\cap C))=m(A\cap C)-m(B\cap C)$.  For example, $A = \varnothing, B=C=[0,1]$ and Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @GEdgar How about the $X$ which is the whole space and $E, F$ is Borel set. Do we have $m(X\cap E - F \cap E)=m(X\cap E)-m(F \cap E)$?

Comment: We have $m(A - B) = m(A) - m(B)$ when $B$ is a subset of $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a nice trick you can use to evaluate any such set equality. It works whenever you want to see whether two simple set expressions are equal. With simple set expressions, I mean expressions that don't care about the nature of any set's elements, and only use elementary set operations (union, intersection, set difference, symmetric difference, complement).

The range of applicability may be wider, but for simple set expressions I know for sure it works.

The trick works as follows:

1. First, take note of the number $n$ of sets occurring (if there's a “full set” — the one relative to which complements are formed — then don't count that).

   In your case, we have three sets: $A$, $B$, $C$. Thus $n=3$.
2. Define the full set as $U=\{0,1,\ldots,2^n-1\}$.

   In your case, it's $U=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$.
3. Assign consecutive powers of two to  all the sets, starting at $2^0=1$.

   In your case, we have $A\mapsto 1, B\mapsto 2, C\mapsto 4$.
4. Write all members of the full set as sum of powers of two (equivalently, write them as binary), and then put them in every set whose power it contains.

   For example, $0$ is the empty sum, thus it goes into none of the sets. $1=2^0$, therefore it only goes into $A$. $5=2^0+2^2$, therefore it goes into $A$ and $C$.

   In your case, we get $A=\{1,3,5,7\}$, $B=\{2,3,6,7\}$, $C=\{4,5,6,7\}$.

   It probably is more obvious what happens if we write the numbers in binary, padded to three digits with leading zeros: $A=\{001,011,101,111\}$, $B=\{010,011,110,111\}$, $C=\{100,101,110,111\}$
5. Using those sets, test your equation. If it works with those sets, it works with any set. If it does not work with those sets, it obviously doesn't hold.

   In your case, we get on the left side:
   \begin{align}
   (A\setminus B)\cap C
   &= (\{1,3,5,7\}\setminus\{2,3,6,7\})\cap\{4,5,6,7\}\\
   &= \{1,5\}\cap\{4,5,6,7\}\\
   &= \{5\}
   \end{align}
   and on the right side:
   \begin{align}
   (A\cap C)\setminus(B\cap C)
   &= (\{1,3,5,7\}\cap\{4,5,6,7\})\setminus(\{2,3,6,7\}\cap\{4,5,6,7\})\\
   &= \{5,7\}\setminus\{6,7\}\\
   &= \{5\}
   \end{align}
   As you see, both give the same result, thus the relation holds.

The reason this works is that whether an element is in the set described by the expression only depends on which of the sets it is in. The method above makes sure that all possible combinations occur, therefore the calculation covers all possible cases.

Comment: Nice, I wouldn't ever have thought of it that way. The binary representations could be thought of as vectors $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb F_2$ and then we could define sets as, e.g. in this case $A=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb F_2:~z=1\}$. Will take note of it in case I ever need to teach elementary set theory.

Comment: @B.Núñez: Yes, that's another way to represent that. Of course more people know about integers and powers of two, or about binary representations, than about $\mathbb F_2$.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with measure theory, so I will answer your main question on set theory.

$(A-B)\cap C=(A\cap C) -(B\cap C)?$ is indeed true. To show it, use set algebra.

$LHS = (A-B)\cap C = (A\cap B')\cap C$

$RHS = (A\cap C) -(B\cap C)$

$= (A\cap C)\cap(B\cap C)'$

$= (A\cap C)\cap (B' \cup C')$ (de Morgan's Law)

$=((A\cap C)\cap B')\cup ((A\cap C)\cap C')$ (distributivity of intersection over union)

$=((A\cap C)\cap B')\cup (A\cap (C\cap C'))$ (associativity of intersection)

$=((A\cap C)\cap B')\cup (A\cap \emptyset)$

$=((A\cap C)\cap B')\cup \emptyset$

$=(A\cap C)\cap B'$

$=A\cap (C\cap B')$ (associativity of intersection)

$=A\cap (B'\cap C)$ (commutativity of intersection)

$=(A\cap B')\cap C$ (associativity of intersection)

$\therefore LHS=RHS \ (QED)$