# Simplify a set (A ∪ B)\(A \ (A ∩ B))

Tags: set-theory

I'm trying to simplify a set and I'm stuck.
The set is: $(A \cup B) \setminus (A \setminus (A \cap B))$.

If someone can help with some instructions and explanations it would be great!

Comment: It simplifies to $B$.  You can see this a number of ways... one of the most tactile ways would be using a sequence of venn diagrams, shading appropriate regions.  A more tedious way might be to rewrite everything with set logic.  The easiest way in my opinion is to recognize that every combination of $A$'s and $B$'s, however ugly, will result in some disjoint union of the four regions, $A\cap B, A^c\cap B, A\cap B^c$ and $A^c\cap B^c$.  Test to see if an arbitrary element from each of those regions exists in your set in question and simplify from there

Comment: The expression in the question doesn't make sense, while the one in the title does.

Comment: I edited it in TeX.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks, Venn diagram was a good idea, can't believe i didn't think of that myself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \in (A \cup B) \setminus (A \setminus (A \cap B))$, then $(x \in A$ or $x \in B)$ and ($x \not \in A$ and $(x \in A$ and $x \in B$)).
Since $x \in A$, $x \not \in A$ is a contradiction, it must be that $x \in B$, meaning that the expression simplifies into $B$.
You could also draw Venn diagrams to get a visual as to what's actually happening.

Comment: Venn diagram and your explanation made it clearer for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is intuitively obvious: you have the set of elements which are in $A$ or in $B$, and you remove the elements in $A$, with the exception of those which are also in $B$. In other words, you remove only those elements in $A$ which are $outside$ $B$. Therefore, there remains $B$.

Answer (score -1):

Since this is a simple set expression involving two sets, we can check it by just using $A=\{1,3\}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3430920/34930) for details).

Thus we have

\begin{align}
(A\cup B)\setminus(A\setminus(A\cap B))
&= (\{1,3\}\cup\{2,3\})\setminus(\{1,3\}\setminus(\{1,3\}\cap\{2,3\}))\\
&= \{1,2,3\}\setminus(\{1,3\}\setminus\{3\})\\
&= \{1,2,3\}\setminus\{1\}\\
&= \{2,3\} = B
\end{align}

Therefore the set expression simplifies to $B$.

Comment: An example is not a proof.

Comment: @BernardMassé: Did you follow the link? In this case, the *specifically crafted* example *is* a proof.